# Prototype cell won't show content

Tags: uitableview, ios7, custom-cell

I have designed a cell in storyboard, then created a custom UITableViewCell subclass (BasicCell) and assigned it to it. Also set the proper identifiers. I created outlets of the custom cell in that class. Then in my UITableViewController subclass (where I have two types of prototype cells), the cells content won't show up. What am I doing wrong?

**BasicCell.h**

```
@interface BasicCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *scorevalue;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *avgvalue;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *rankvalue;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *scorelabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *categorylabel;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *ranklabel;

@end
```

**TableViewController.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     static NSString *CellIdentifierBasic = @"basic";
     static NSString *CellIdentifierDetailed = @"detailed";

    UITableViewCell *cell;

    if(indexPath.row==0){
        // Create first cell

        cell = [[BasicCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifierBasic];


    }

    else{

        // Create all others

        cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierDetailed forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }


    // Configure the cell...

    switch ([indexPath row])
    {
        case 0:
        {

            BasicCell *basicCell = (BasicCell *)cell;

            basicCell.scorelabel.text = @"test";
            basicCell.categorylabel.text = @"test";
            basicCell.ranklabel.text = @"test";

            basicCell.scorevalue.text = @"test";
            basicCell.avgvalue.text = @"test";
            basicCell.rankvalue.text = @"test";



        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your storyboard,

1. Create two prototype cell.
2. Change one of your prototype cell's custom class. Set it `BasicCell`.
3. Make sure that  you set appropriate cell identifier for each type of cell.
4. Don't **alloc init** if it's **indexPath.row == 0**  but **dequeue** with appropriate identifier.

It should work.

Note: You should declare your IBOutlets as weak not as strong. Cell's view has already strong pointer to them. You don't have to own them.

Comment: 4. was the problem. Thank you